# Objective-c Sections table send different data to another table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have one tableView with 10 sections (categories). And I have another table with news from this category. I am fetching the data from different links and want to send news list when I'll click on some. Which method I should to use?

**Example:**

1. Table Categories

Prototype cells on both tables

cell - News

cell - politics ----> I am clicking this cell and need send data to another table view

cell - whatever

Or Simply create 10 static cells with 10 segue identifiers?

Could you please suggest me how I can implement this?

Comment: Have you created the basic master detail project in Xcode and taken a look at how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the categories cell will never change and they will always be 10 then you can use static cells if the number of categories might change then use prototype cells.

Regarding the segues, just one segue from your first view controller to the next one.

In your second VC you can create a property named, let's say "category" and then, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can programmatically call the segue via `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:maybeTheCategoryString];` then in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` you can get get the destination view controller of your segue aka. your second view controller and set the category property.